# Historical accounts of a oft-cited quip by astronomer Walter Baade

Tags: physics, astronomy

I am looking for any documented, historical reference to an oft-cited humorous reply by German astronomer [Walter Baade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Baade) (1893 – 1960).

After having asked if other astronomers were familliar with the quote below in  [astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35516/11806), I managed to contact the person I had heard it from and they sent me the following which I have posted there as an answer:

Baade was asked:

> If you had your life to live over, would you be an astronomer again?

To which he answered:

> Only if the ratio of total to selective absorption is everywhere the same.

which was meant to be a humorous reply. Comments there point to the web page [Dust in Galaxies](https://pages.astronomy.ua.edu/keel/galaxies/dust.html) that also recounts the quote but with a slightly different wording but alas does also not provide a source. A comment there mentioned this SE community, so I came here to ask a related but different question:

Are there any historical records or published accounts of the above exchange taking place?